# Use a Button like a FileUpload in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have this situation:

[image]

Two normal ASP.NET controls.
But I want to hide the FileUpload control, and remain with the only Button.

Something so trivial is causing me more problems than expected.This is my implementation:

**ASPX**:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Carica Documento" OnClientClick="showBrowseDialog();" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hideButton" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showBrowseDialog() {
        var fileuploadctrl = document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
        fileuploadctrl.click();

        var btn = document.getElementById('<%= hideButton.ClientID %>');
        btn.click();
    }
</script>
```

**C#**:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string address = Server.MapPath("") + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(address);
            //...
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this layoutt

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" Style="display: none" runat="server" onchange="upload()" />
<input type="button" value="Carica Documento"  onclick="showBrowseDialog()"/>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hideButton" Text="" Style="display: none;" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showBrowseDialog() {
        var fileuploadctrl = document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
        fileuploadctrl.click();
    }

    function upload() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%= hideButton.ClientID %>');
        btn.click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thx! This works! Only, I became crazy because at first I did not change the <asp: Button ... /> with <input ... /> ... but once done it worked! I wonder why the asp:Button didn't work out ... anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Because thats server side control and it make postback on every event, i think another solution its put contol in updatepanel=)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood this. 
Do you want to show only one button instead of two which will open the file dialogue box and after you select a file, do the upload job?

Comment: Exactly. I want to show just the button. If the user click on it, can choose a file in the dialog and upload that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.......

## ASPX:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Carica Documento" OnClientClick="return showBrowseDialog();" onclick="UploadButton_Click"/>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showBrowseDialog() 
    {
        document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').click();    
    }
    </script>
```

## C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileUpload1.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
        }

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string address = Server.MapPath("~/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(address);
                    //...
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution needed the user to only have to click a single button to upload and then process the file.

Using JQuery and Bootstrap 4x to help, I used a slightly different approach using 3 controls (2 ASPX).  Only the "btnUploadFile" is displayed.

```
<input id="btnUploadFile" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Select CSV File and Upload" onclick="$('#FileUploadControl').click();"/>
    
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" CssClass="d-none" onchange="$('#btnUploadAndProcess').trigger('click'); return false;" accept=".csv" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUploadAndProcess" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" CssClass="d-none" OnClick="btnUploadAndProcess_Click"/>
```

When "btnUploadFile" is clicked, the "FileUploadControl" onclick event opens the OPEN file dialog. When a file is selected the "btnUploadAndProcess_Click" C# method runs.

```
protected void btnUploadAndProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile) {
            try { 
                   ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
}
```